# Fedora + Apache + Phusion passenger + Rails shows default apache page (always)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, fedora, phusion

Even though there is a huge amount of information about this subject I'm still stuck at the *apache default page* shown by the server. The worse part is that everything seems to work properly.

I've installed everything using `dnf`, even the ruby gems

I'm using

- Fedora 22 Server minimal installation `4.2.6-200.fc22.x86_64`
- Apache `2.4.17`
- Phusion passenger `4.0.53`

Packages that I've installed

```
# dnf install nodejs ruby rubygem-rails ruby-devel rubygem-json rubygem-debug_inspector rubygem-byebug rubygem-sqlite3 httpd mod_passenger
```

Passenger config file *(edited after @bobomoreno answer)*

```
$ cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/passenger.conf
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
   PassengerRoot /usr/share/passenger//phusion_passenger/locations.ini
   PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby
   PassengerEnable on

   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName 10.10.15.219
       ServerAdmin los_true@gmail.com

       DocumentRoot /var/www/html/los_true/public

       ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/tsc-error.log
       CustomLog /var/log/httpd/tsc-access.log common

       RackEnv development

       <Directory /var/www/html/los_true/public>
           Allow from all
           Options -MultiViews
           Require all granted
       </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Firewall working fine

```
# firewall-cmd --list-all
public (default, active)
  interfaces: eth0
  sources: 
  services: dhcpv6-client http https mdns ssh
  ports:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

SELinux permissive (until everything else work fine, then I will change it to enforcing)

```
$ sestatus 
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      29
```

Apache server running without errors

```
$ systemctl status -l httpd
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since sáb 2015-11-28 20:41:05 CLT; 24min ago
 Main PID: 25649 (httpd)
   Status: "Total requests: 1; Idle/Busy workers 100/0;Requests/sec: 0.00068; Bytes served/sec:   3 B/sec"
   CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
           ├─25649 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─25650 /usr/libexec/nss_pcache 1802248 off /etc/httpd/alias
           ├─25671 PassengerWatchdog
           ├─25674 PassengerHelperAgent
           ├─25679 PassengerLoggingAgent
           ├─25689 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─25690 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─25691 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─25692 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           ├─25693 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
           └─25705 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

nov 28 20:41:04 ip210.15.priv.inf.utfsm.cl systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
nov 28 20:41:05 ip210.15.priv.inf.utfsm.cl systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
```

Passenger started and running with no errors listed

```
# cat /var/log/httpd/error_log | grep 'Phusion\|Passenger'
[ 2015-11-28 21:43:34.3687 26203/7f416653f740 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:650 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.26198/generation-0/request
[ 2015-11-28 21:43:34.3807 26209/7ff9a135b840 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:321 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.26198/generation-0/logging
[ 2015-11-28 21:43:34.3817 26200/7fdd4c2bf740 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:728 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
[ 2015-11-28 21:43:34.4808 26223/7fb79dc8d740 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:650 ]: PassengerHelperAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.26198/generation-1/request
[ 2015-11-28 21:43:34.4912 26229/7f643095a840 agents/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:321 ]: PassengerLoggingAgent online, listening at unix:/tmp/passenger.1.0.26198/generation-1/logging
[ 2015-11-28 21:43:34.4916 26220/7efd30072740 agents/Watchdog/Main.cpp:728 ]: All Phusion Passenger agents started!
[Sat Nov 28 21:43:34.498645 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 26198] AH00163: Apache/2.4.17 (Fedora) mod_auth_gssapi/1.3.0 mod_nss/2.4.16 NSS/3.19.3 Basic ECC mod_wsgi/4.4.8 Python/2.7.10 Phusion_Passenger/4.0.53 configured -- resuming normal operations

# cat /var/log/httpd/tsc-error.log
#
```

Rails application working (It was tested in a local machine and it worked fine)

```
$ cd /var/www/html/los_true
$ ./bin/bundle install
Using rake 10.4.2
Using i18n 0.7.0
...
Using web-console 2.2.1
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
$ ./bin/rake db:migrate
$
```

So I have truly no idea what I'm doing wrong. Also there is only one weird thing about passenger, it says that is not running but it redirects the `public` folder fine (I can see the `*.html` files located in the `public` folder if I put them in the URL, `http://10.10.15.219/404.html` for example)

```
$ passenger-status 
ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running.
```

So please if anyone have any idea of what's the problem in here please help me :c because I really don't know what else to do

Comment: By the way please excuse my English :) I tried my best

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33222480/apache-redmine-403-premissions-are-good) :'D

It turned out to be the `autoindex` module the source of evil. If you comment the line

```
...
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
...
```

in `/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-base.conf` and remove the file `autoindex.conf`

```
# mv /etc/httpd/conf.d/autoindex.conf /etc/httpd/conf.d/autoindex.conf.bak
```

you will get the rail views working :')

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing

```
passenger_enabled on;
```

in your virtual host definition

Comment: I tried adding `PassengerEnable on` inside both the virtual host definition and outside, but it still shows the default page :(